# Can't Define Services in CAS Overlay Template v. 6.4 (Docker)

Tags: cas

Using the [cas-overlay-template](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template), I am trying to access the CAS login screen from HTTP(s)://localhost/admin:

https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%2Fadmin

To do this, I am trying to define services inside **/etc/cas/services/services.json**:

```
{
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
    "serviceId" : "^http://.*",
    "name" : "http_services",
    "allowed": true,
    "ssoEnabled": true,
    "anonymousAccess": false,
    "id" : 1,
    "evaluationOrder" : 1
},
{
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
    "serviceId" : "^https://.*",
    "name" : "https_services",
    "allowed": true,
    "ssoEnabled": true,
    "anonymousAccess": false,
    "id" : 2,
    "evaluationOrder" : 2
}
```

FWIW, I've also tried to define a service file according to the pattern described [here](https://dacurry-tns.github.io/deploying-apereo-cas/building_server_service-registry_configure-the-service-registry.html).

In **/etc/config/cas.properties**, I have defined the following:

```
cas.server.name=https://cas.example.org:8443
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas
cas.service-registry.json.location=classpath:/services
logging.config=file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
```

Finally in **build.gradle**, I have added the support for JSON service registry:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-json-service-registry:${casServerVersion}"
}
```

No matter what I do, after building and running the Docker image, I always get the same thing:

```
INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [0] service(s) from [JsonServiceRegistry].>
```

When I go to the URL, I am told

> "Application Not Authorized to Use CAS".

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus question: https://cas.example.org:8443 does not work in the URL. Do I need to edit something in the docker container to get this to map onto my local machine?

**-- UPDATE --**

As was said in the answer, I needed to create a single, named service:

```
// File: /etc/cas/services/today-12345.json
{
    "@class":"org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
    "serviceId":"^(https|http|imaps)://.*",
    "name":"today",
    "id" :12345
}
```

To part 2 of Misagh's answer, based on what I'm seeing in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/blob/master/Dockerfile), the /etc/cas/services directory simply doesn't exist by the time ./gradlew runs, and so the services aren't registered.

If I put in my **cas.properties file**

```
cas.service-registry.json.location=/etc/cas/services
```

I get a stacktrace that includes:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [etc/cas/services] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

If I /bin/sh into the container, I can see the service inside of the /etc/cas/services directory.

I've been getting around this by simply copying the .json file after the Docker containers have been built

```
docker cp ~/emu/cas-overlay-template/etc/cas/services/today-12345.json [CONTID]:/tmp/services
```

(/tmp/services because that's where the console output says it's watching for services)

-- **SOLUTION** --

The path had to be:

```
cas.service-registry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/services
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Multiple things.

- You have your services in `/etc/cas/services/services.json` as a single JSON file. That is not correct. You need to have 1 file per 1 app. Consult the documentation for JSON service registry.
- `cas.service-registry.json.location` should point to the directory location where such JSON files are found. You need to make sure this location in your Docker setup points or contains your service definitions.

Comment: Thanks, Misagh. The path had to be in the following format: "cas.service-registry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/services".

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I think the location /etc/cas/services it is defined in the apereo cas standalone profile. If you define another spring profile it will look for /tmp/services. It happened to me while configuring cas in docker environment and wanting to use a test profile.